# How do I add tags to this theme?

Tags: tumblr, tumblr-themes, tumblr-tags

I've tried pasting in the code before the `{/block:Posts}` line, but it just puts them right on top of the next post, like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rtKZE.jpg).

Here's the whole code for the theme: https://raw.github.com/edadams/Themes/master/Win98.html

Comment: Have you tried replacing {Body} with the code? It looks like it goes here: <div class="body">
                                    {Body}
                                </div>

Comment: I tried that and [something](http://imageshack.us/a/img842/4723/onede.jpg) [else](http://imageshack.us/a/img834/361/twosj.jpg) happened.

Comment: Sorry, I thought that was where you wanted the tags. Where do you want them?

Comment: They're fine there, but they replace the text in the post and they don't always show up.

Comment: Can you show me the code that outputs your posts and tags? I think if we combine that code we can get both to come out in the same place in the right order.

Answer (score 1):

Try placing it before the `.bottom <div>`

```
{block:HasTags}
   {block:Tags}
      <div class="tags">
           <a href="{TagURL}">{Tag}</a>
      </div>
   {/block:Tags}
{/block:HasTags}

<div class="bottom"></div>
                </div>

{/block:Posts}
```

Should give something like the following

[image: #dog #menswear #swag]

The tags above are #dog #menswear #swag

Comment: Nice looking dog there!